# Connect to Socket server from Actionscript 3 AIR application

Tags: java, actionscript-3, sockets, flex4, air

I read through the method to connect to a socket server : http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_5.html

I wrote an AIR application to connect to the java server code, but the client cannot connect. What is missing in the code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" backgroundColor="#D5F8C3">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import flash.net.XMLSocket;



            var socket:XMLSocket;

            public function b1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

                var socket:XMLSocket;
                socket.connect("127.0.0.1",8080);
                socket.send("Hello");
                //socket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onData);

            }




        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->


    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button id="b1" x="285" y="162" label="Send Text" width="201" height="105" click="b1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for CONNECTED event before sending data. Also, be sure you've managed crossdomain security (look at : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c60.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c63)

Server/client code exemple : [Air 2 ServerSocket Crossdomain problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947378/air-2-serversocket-crossdomain-problem)

Comment: thanks for the help..how do i receive a CONNECTED event? please let me know with some code example

Comment: I just added a link into my response

Comment: That worked.Thanks. However I'm not able to get any data back from the java server, I added these lines to the server : Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(incoming.getOutputStream( ));
             Date now = new Date( );

                out.write(now.toString( ) +"\r\n");

             
                String str = readerIn.readLine(); And on the as3 side added : private function onData(event : DataEvent) : void
   {
     trace("[" + event.type + "] " + event.data);
    }